# Adding Alt-Text to Images in ConTeXt

Tags: context

I've been looking at ways to add alt-text to tagged images in PDFs.

From the mailing list in [this thread](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2015/082505.html), it appears that it should be possible to do

```
\externalfigure[t:/sources/cow.pdf][label=whatever]
```

in order to generate a tagged image with the alt-text being the same the label.

This doesn't work for me so I'm wondering if there is a different way to do this or if it wasn't added?

Comment: Apparently `Alt` text is so irrelevant that it has been removed from the tagging routine, see [`lpdf-tag.lua`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/e52e58ff4a7007ca774905727391e5f78135f98d/tex/context/base/mkiv/lpdf-tag.lua#L255).  I would recommend you only use graphics within a figure which should be tagged with the caption.

Comment: @HenriMenke Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician No, because my comment is not an answer.